# How to ensure to call function after all other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 4-5 JavaScript functions which calls ajax and respond after sometime, but for example I am giving example of 3 functions without ajax code.

Here I want to ensure that `func3` will call after two other functions `func1` and `func2`.

```js
func3();
func1();
func2();


function func1(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("func1");
  }, 2000);
}
function func2(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("func2");
  }, 3000);
}
function func3(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("func3");
  }, 1000);
}
```

I want total time would be 4 seconds. `func1` and `func2` would run simultaneously in 3 seconds and then `func3` in 1 second.

Comment: Create custom events? or Promises?

Comment: Use promises to do this. It would also be far more helpful to see your actual AJAX code than an approximation of it using timeouts

Comment: @evolutionxbox : Sorry no idea, please help by giving any good article or link

Comment: I tend to use google for that.

Comment: [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: I vote for Promise.

Answer (score 2):

Call them at the end of the func before?

```js
func3();


function func1(){
    console.log("func1");
    func2();
}
function func2(){
    console.log("func2");
}
function func3(){
    console.log("func3");
    func1();
}
```

**Edit 1:**

```js
func1();


function func1(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("func1");
    func2();
  }, 1500);
}
function func2(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("func2");
    func3();
  }, 1500);
}
function func3(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("func3");
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add `setTimeout` just like I added in my question , so that I can check that it is taking 4 Seconds exactly, Also `func3` would execute at last. In your example its executing first.

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't understand your english

Comment: In your edit `func1` is printing in 2 seconds `func2` in 3 seconds and `func3` in 1 second total `6` seconds I want it should be `4` seconds. `func1` and `func2` would run simultaneously in `3` seconds and then `func3`. I think now you got my point.

Comment: Edited as you asked ^^

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
let promises = [];
let ajaxCall = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('ajaxCall');
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve();
  },1000);
});

let fn1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('fn1');
  ajaxCall.then(() => {
    resolve();
  });
});

let fn2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('fn2');
  ajaxCall.then(() => {
    resolve();
  });
});

promises.push(fn1); 
promises.push(fn2);

Promise.all((promises)).then(() => {
  console.log('fn3');
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If I call ajax it will take some time to sleep execution I used `setTimeout` So would your code be like this : https://jsfiddle.net/6b8ub0g0/1/

Comment: @detective404 See edited answer, your ajax call is also a promise, which answer you can wait for, so fn1 and fn2 will wait for the ajaxcall to complete. And promise.all will wait for fn1 and fn2 to complete before executing fn3.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick primer on Promises:

A promise is an object that basically says, "This work isn't done yet, but I'll let you know when it is."

When you create a Promise, you can attach callback functions using `.then()`. When the promise is *resolved* - that is to say, it's work is finished - all of the callbacks will be executed. You can also attach callbacks with `.fail()` or something similar, and these will be executed if the Promise is *rejected*.

In your case, you might do something like:

```
func1().then(func2).then(func3);

function func1(){
    var p = new Promise();
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log("func1");
        p.resolve();
    }, 2000);
    return p;
}
function func2(){
    var p = new Promise();
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log("func2");
        p.resolve();
    }, 3000);
    return p;
}
function func3(){
    var p = new Promise();
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log("func3");
        p.resolve();
    }, 1000);
    return p;
}
```

In addition, most Promise Libraries have a `.whenAll()` type function. This takes multiple Promises and calls its `.then()` callbacks when all promises have completed. So you could do:

```
whenAll(func1(), func2()).then(func3);
```

If you are in an environment where you can use EcmaScript6, there is a built in Promise library. Read [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for information on that library.

Otherwise, I strongly recommend [jQuery's](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) promise library.

Note: The above code is just psuedocode. Read the documentation to see how to actually implement the Promises in those frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I made it as I want, like this. But I don't know its good of bad practice, I am not aware of promise and get some answer's but those were not working.

```js
start = 0;
func1();
func2();

function func1(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("func1");
    start++;
    if(start==2){
      func3();
    }
  }, 2000);
}
function func2(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("func2");
    start++;
    if(start==2){
      func3();
    }    
  }, 3000);
}
function func3(){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    console.log("func3");
  }, 1000);
}
```

Note : first function `func1` prints in `2` seconds `func2` in `1` second because `2` already gone, and then `func3` in `1` second total `4` seconds cheers :)